# Pandas read_csv keeps returning null columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a CSV file that has 15 rows and 22 columns. Every time I try importing the file, it excludes the 11th and 12th columns.

What's weird is that if I try this with a file of 20 columns or less, this issue doesn't happen.

Any help would be appreciated.

I've updated the code below and tried a different csv file. As you can see from the output, it is not just that the columns aren't showing when they print, but when I try querying it using SQLDF, it says the column doesn't exist.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
mydata_demographics= pd.read_csv('Demographics2.csv', header=0)
mydata_demographics.head()

from pandasql import sqldf  
query_T = """
select 
b1.customer_id, 
b1.YOB, b1.NumChildren, b1.City, b1.Population_K, b1.HouseHolds,  
b1.HHAveSize,      
b1.PopUnder5, b1.Pop5_16, b1.Pop17_25, b1.Pop26_35, 
b1.Pop36_45, b1.Pop46_55, b1.Pop56_65, b1.PopOver65,
b1.HHIncomeMed, b1.WhtCollarOcc, b1.BluCollarOcc
from
mydata_demographics  B1
"""

mydata_demo_T= sqldf(query_T, globals())
mydata_demo_T.head()
```

Here is a sample of the original data (again, there are 22 columns, 15 rows):

```
HouseHolds   HHAveSize   PopUnder5   Pop5_16 
       277         2.2         5.8      14.9
       277         2.2         5.8      14.9
       277         2.2         5.8      14.9
       292         2.3         5.8      14.9
```

And here's a sample of the result:

```
      City  Population_K  HouseHolds       ...          Pop5_16    
0  Chicago           623         277       ...             14.9         
1  Chicago           623         277       ...             14.9          
2  Chicago           623         277       ...             14.9          
3  Chicago           684         292       ...             14.8
```

Now when I run the SQL code, it gives the following error that the column HHAveSize does not exist:

```
PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: b1.HHAveSize     
[SQL: '\nselect \nb1.customer_id, \nb1.YOB, b1.NumChildren, b1.City,   
b1.Population_K,
```

When I run 
    mydata_demographics.shape

it shows that there are 22 columns:
    mydata_demographics.shape
    Out[45]: (15, 22)

Comment: Can you please post the actual raw csv file data?

Comment: Can you post the actual result? Are there dots between the rows as you have shown in the example? Because that just means you have the columns but due to a large column count it doesn't show everything.

Comment: Try `print mydata_1.shape` to see actual # of columns

Comment: I added some additional code above. It is showing that I do have 22 fields, but still if I try to do any kind of data manipulation, fields 11-22 do not exist

Answer (score 0):

As Shweta mentioned in the comments, the columns are probably there they're just not being displayed. If you want to be able to see all the columns you can print your data frame like:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_columns', len(mydata_1.columns), 'display.max_rows', 4):
    print mydata_1
```

This will print the first 4 rows and all of the columns.